# Is there a way to make an iterable that gets populated concurrently but can still be used as a regular iterable?

Tags: python, concurrency

Say I have a function that somehow procures or generates "things" (like web page data, images from a camera, etc) in an I/O bound fashion. I also have a function that does something with those things in a CPU-bound fashion. Below is a working example.

```py
import time


def make_things(n_things) -> list:
    things = []
    for i in range(n_things):
        # Simulate IO bound.
        time.sleep(1)
        things.append(i)
    return things


def do_something_with_things(things: list):
    for thing in things:
        # Simulate CPU bound.
        start_cpu_bound = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_cpu_bound < 1:
            _ = 1 + 1
        print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.1f}", f"#{thing}")


start_time = time.time()
things = make_things(2)
do_something_with_things(things)
print(f"Total time: {time.time() - start_time:.1f}")
```

It prints:

```
3.0 #0
4.0 #1
Total time: 4.0
```

I could draw a diagram showing the order of execution. First two things are made, then each is processed.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is:

[image]

**Importantly, I have two requirements to add**.

1. I want to leave the second function mostly unchanged. I could relax it to taking in an iterable rather than a list (which amounts to changing the type hint).
2. When I'm finished going through the things once, they become like a regular list. The things are cached because I've already done the work of procuring/generating them.

If we drop the toy example for a moment, I can reframe my question. Is there some sort of way I can make something that is like an iterable which behaves as follows?

```py
# This line will hang until the next item is available, or it will 
# exit the for loop if my special_iterable says it's done:
for item in special_iterable:
    # Now, the machinery that's populating the special iterable
    # is still at work, preparing the next item for me via a
    # I/O bound work (or not, if there's nothing left to prepare).
    
    # Here I do some CPU bound stuff.
    
# Once everthing is done, my special iterable is no longer so special.
# I can iterate over it again and it has all the values cached.
# It's basically a list.
for item in special iterable:
    # I immediately have access to the same items from before.
```

The advantage of this special iterable is that all code that needs to  iterate through it can act as if it's iterating through a list. This means I don't have to write the code differently for whatever it is that happens to consume the special iterable first.

Edit: I realised it's not necessary to wait till the first for-loop to begin populating the iterable. I could also create the iterable, do a bunch of CPU-bound stuff that has nothing to do with the iterable, and then iterate through it. Maybe by then it already has some elements populated, it doesn't matter. The point is that I can start iterating through it even when it's not done populating, but that I won't reach a StopIteration until it's fully populated.

```
iterable = make_iterable_somehow()  # it will have 10 items, each taking 1 second to procure/generate

# I do a bunch of CPU/bound stuff that takes me 5 seconds.

# This will go through the first 5 items very fast but then have
# to wait 1 second for each of the next 5
for item in iterable:
    # Something that takes 0.00001 seconds

# This will go through all the items very fast.
for item in iterable:
    # Something that takes 0.00001 seconds
```

Comment: Write a generator function, it uses `yield` to return the next item.

Comment: @Barmar pretty sure that won't allow for concurrency. Nor will the items generated by it be reusable (unless I explicitly cache them on the consumer end). If I want to iterate through it again, I will have to do all the I/O bound work again.

Comment: Look into asyncio/multiprocessing.Queue. Might be able to wrap it, but I don't see much need for it to behave like a regular iterable.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 thanks! asyncio seemed like it needed more changes than I actually need. Currently working on making a class that takes in an iterable of the nature described above and consumes/caches it on a separate thread. It has its own `__iter__` that accounts for the cache and remaining items to be awaited. In doing so, I'm having some "fun" with concurrency concepts. If there's no good answer when I'm done, I'll post it here.

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote my earlier comment I didn't notice that you were looking for concurrency.

Comment: @Barmar that's okay, I've made a few edits to make it clear since

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Queue


async def worker(requests, responses):
    print("Worker running")

    while True:
        try:
            # Try getting the request, but if the queue is empty, wait for it to be filled.
            request = await requests.get()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Worker cancelled")
            break

        # process request
        if request == "STOP":
            break

        # put response
        await responses.put(f"{request} processed")

        # FYI, if you don't sleep in asyncio, you can starve the event loop.
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    print("Worker done")


async def main_logic(requests, responses):
    # Put tasks in the queue, and a STOP for each worker. This could be in your parallel producer loop instead.
    for i in range(10):
        await requests.put(i)
    for _ in range(4):
        await requests.put("STOP")

    print("Main logic running")

    # Instantly consume all results as they come in - lets allow a few failures in case the workers are slow to start.
    failed = 0
    while failed < 3:
        try:
            response = responses.get_nowait()
            print(f"Main loop got: '{response}'")

        except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            failed += 1


def main():
    requests = Queue()
    responses = Queue()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    workers = [asyncio.ensure_future(worker(requests, responses)) for _ in range(4)]

    # We could have a producer_loop as well as main_logic, along with however many workers we want.
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(main_logic(requests, responses), *workers))

    print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The multiprocessing variant will be similar, except passing queues between processes isn't fun. You'll probably want to use a pool and you'll use global queues in the parent process to make them available to children.

Now, we could make an iterator with `iter(queue.get, "STOP")` or similar, but as you see, how you iterate a queue is not very trivial and varies depending on producer/consumer context greatly. There's just no way around the overhead for main producer/consumer logic either. (For a taste of what you'll encounter, try converting the while loop in main logic to use the `await responses.get()` and consider the exit condition still.)

I personally don't like the idea of making a Queue an opaque iterator for this reason. Not everything gets hidden by dunders sensibly. Still, if you really want to try, read up on implementing `__next__` and `__iter__` methods for `class YourQueue(conclib.Queue)`. It's going to be a major pain in the arse for anything non-trivial.

Personally, keep premature optimization in mind: If you don't need the concurrency yet, don't bother until you're having performance issues. Odds are what the slowdown really turns out to be won't be what you think it will be. Also, thanks to the GIL, threading itself is pretty much just heavy async. Personally, I say port out your inner loops when necessary and don't worry about optimizing "Python performance", that's oxymoronic :)

Comment: Thanks. I've run out of time for the day so I will check back tomorrow. As an aside, responding to your last paragraph, this is driven by the need for optimization in a complex pipeline where I didn't want to create a mess of the neat code that's already there. I have a function that makes two cameras take a picture in sequence. They each take 400 ms. I have a deep neural network that processes them, and it takes 400 ms for each. But I don't want to start littering the pipeline with concurrency code.

Comment: That sounds like a possible use case, sounds like you've thought about it. It's not generally reasonable to just drop a codebase :o) Personally, given that application and trying to keep it simple - I might try multiprocessing.Pool.map. It can avoid the need for Queues, which you probably don't need if you're just trying to do IO bound in parallel and the cpu bound can be sequential. You'd probably end up recreating a pool in a loop with new inputs at that step, then do your main logic on map's results. I'll think more about your actual problem.

Comment: I just posted my own answer. I prefer it to yours because, as far as I understand, I wouldn't have been able to achieve the end effect (that I describe at the end of my answer), because I'd have to litter my pipeline with a bunch of concurrency related code. Would love to get your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> Once everthing is done, my special iterable is no longer so special.

That sounds as if your program progresses through two phases. Rather than try to make one object that serves the needs of both phases, why not use two separate objects?

- I would use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to pass objects from the producer thread to the consumer thread during the first phase, and I would have the consumer thread append each consumed object to a list. Then, "Once everything is done,"
- I would be able to iterate over the list as many times as needed during the second phase.

Comment: Thanks! I think I wanted to hide away that transition so that the consumer code can pretty much pretend that it's working with a list. Please see my answer (and the bit at the end that really exemplifies how I need to use it). I'd love to know your thoughts.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare, Maybe I don't understand the relationship between the "consumer code" and the two phases, but your `do_something_with_things` function expects a `things: list` argument. If it's really a `list`, then you ought to be able to do things with it like ask for the last member, `things[-1]`, or ask how many members, `len(things)`. Those operations lose their meaning though when some other thread is concurrently adding things to the list. On the other hand, during that first phase, the consumer might want to _wait_ for the next thing, which is an operation that makes no sense...

Comment: ...when it's given a `list`. The least-common denominator between a queue and a list probably would be either a custom [_iterator_](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) or, as Moses McCabe suggested, a [_generator_](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Either of those could be constructed so as to let the consumer await-and-get the next `thing`, but the client would be able to do little else with it. The client would have to call some separate function to get a fresh iterator/generator if it wanted to go over the same sequence again.

Comment: I should make the `do_something_with_things` accept something less specific than a list because my real use case only requires `__iter__`, `__len__` and `__getitem__`. But even so, I could make my `FutureIterable` implement everything that a list does, only some of the functions would result in a wait because either a specific item is not yet available (like in my `__getitem__`), or the whole list needs to be available (for something like `__reverse__`)

Comment: Why are you saying that "waiting for the next thing" is an operation that makes no sense?

Comment: On a `list` it makes no sense. There's nothing to wait for.  If you want the `i`th thing, you just ask for `things[i]` and there it is. But when one thread is consuming things that are being produced by some other thread, if the consumer gets ahead of the producer, then it will have to wait until the next thing is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. I write a class that wraps an I/O bound iterator with a caching mechanism.

The use case for this class is when one wishes to concurrently populate a cache with the items returned from an I/O bound iterator. An instance of this class is itself iterable (and subscriptable). Iterating through said instance will iterate through the cache, waiting for it to be fully populated by the wrapped iterable.

```py
class FutureIterable:
    def __init__(self, iterator: Iterator, length: int, sleep_time: float = 0.001):
        """ 
        Args:
            iterator: Any iterator.
            length: The iterator's length, or the the number of elements of the iterator one wishes to cache (though
                this should not exceed the iterator's length).
            sleep_time: Attempting to access yet to be populated elements in the list invokes an indefinite while-loop
                to wait for the requested element to be populated. In order to not hog up CPU time, there is a sleep
                time in between checks. It is advised to set this to something that's relatively insignificant on the
                order of time needed to populate one element of the list.
        """
        self._cache = []
        self._full_length = length
        self._sleep_time = sleep_time
        # Note: append is thread-safe
        # https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe
        self._thread = Thread(target=lambda: [self._cache.append(item) for _, item in zip(range(length), iterator)])
        self._thread.start()

    def __getitem__(self, ix: int):
        """Retrieve an item from the cache.
        
        If the item at index ix is in the cache, return it. If the item is not in the cache but
        is expected to be stored in future, suspend the calling thread and wait until it is available. 
        """

        while True:
            if len(self._cache) <= ix < self._full_length:
                time.sleep(self._sleep_time)
                continue
            else:
                return self._cache[ix]

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self._full_length):
            yield self[i]
```

Here's the example usage:

```py
future_iterable = FutureIterable(some_io_bound_iterable, 10)  # we know the iterable will produce exactly 10 items
# Maybe here we do some work that takes a non-trivial amount of time. At this point a thread is at work
# populating the cache.
# We can try to get an item from the FutureIterable at any time but if that part of the cache is not yet populated,
# we might have to wait.
print(future_iterable[5])
# We can iterate through the FutureIterable at any time, but if we "catch up" with the cache, we'll be bottle-necked
# by the I/O bound wrapped iterable.
for item in future_iterable:
    pass
```

And to further explain how this is useful in my particular use case. I have a pipeline that takes in a list of things. The pipeline is composed of general modules that are supposed to be able to take in a list and mutate its elements somehow.

```py
# The list has say 2 items in it, and each takes 1 second to make.
def pipeline(ls):
    pipeline_module_foo(ls)  # this takes 0.5 seconds per item
    pipeline_module_bar(ls)  # this takes 0.5 seconds per item
    pipeline_module_baz(ls)  # this takes... doesn't matter. You'll see why
```

Some of the pipeline modules work with the elements in `ls` independently and one at a time. Some of them need to consider all elements of `ls` together. The idea is that if the first few elements of my pipeline are the former type. I can leverage concurrency with them. My hope was to not have to make **any** changes to the pipeline modules themselves (because they are meant to be like standalone modules. And with my `FutureIterable` I can get away with just make a change to my pipeline code.

```
def pipeline(future_iterable):
    # Say the first two modules process elements of ls independently.
    for item in future_iterable:
        pipeline_module_foo([item])
        pipeline_module_bar([item])
    pipeline_module_baz(future_iterable)
```

Voila, now I get to process items in the list while they are still being procured (and I saved 1 second)! And I barely had to change my pipeline, so it's still highly modular (although I need to have this scenario that the first few modules process the items independently, otherwise I can't benefit from the concurrency).

I'd still really like to know if there was a better way.